# Can I transfer my applications?

Tags: box-api

I have several [applications](https://app.box.com/developers/services) (OAuth client ID/secret pairs) registered under a personal account.  I need to get them transferred to a company account.  Any idea whether that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

To transfer applications to a different account, you will need to [submit a Box support ticket](https://community.box.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/BoxSearchLithiumTKB).